# C regcomp doesn't compile pattern

Tags: c, regex, base64

I would like to match a **base64** string with this `^(?=(.{4})*$)[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}$` pattern. I've tried different patterns, flags, other languages. I can't use third-party libraries outside of openssl.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main()
{
    const char *data = "dGVzdHRlc3Q=";
    regex_t regex;

    int ret = regcomp(&regex, "^(?=(.{4})*$)[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}$", REG_EXTENDED);
    if (ret)
    {
        printf("Could not compile regex\n");
        return 1;
    }

    ret = regexec(&regex, data, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (!ret)
        printf("Match\n");
    else if (ret == REG_NOMATCH)
        printf("No match\n");

    regfree(&regex);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Posix regex don't have lookaheads (or lookbehinds}. Why do you think you need one?

Comment: This looks like a case where I would advise against using regular expressions. The base64 encoding is simple enough to just try to decode and report errors along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the regex without a lookahead that is not supported by POSIX regex flavor. That lookaround makes sure the string consists of zero or more occurrences of any four chars. By using

```c
int ret = regcomp(&regex, "^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)?$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

you match the same strings. See the [C demo online](https://ideone.com/ei2F07).
*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*` - zero or more occurrences of four ASCII letters, digits, `+` or `/` chars
- `([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)?` - an optional occurrence of four ASCII letters/digits/`/`/`+`, or three ASCII letters/digits/`/`/`+` and then a single `=` char, or to ASCII letters/digits/`/`/`+` and then two `=` chars
- `$` - end of string.